# *iPhone* Unable to symbolicate in Object Allocations instrument

Tags: iphone, xcode, instruments

i run a C++ app from objective-c
I can successfully symbolicate my function names using Shark profiler but not with the Object Allocations instrument.
In the detailed pane, i only see my C++ app name with the hexadecimal value for my C++ functions.

I tried to do a "File/Re-Symbolicate Document", selecting my app folder containing both my app and my Dsym file but nothing change.

Any clues?

My config:
xCode 3.2.2
iPhone SDK 3.2
Snowleopard (10.6.3)

Thx.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this? I'm experiencing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution/cause for my app. When I build the app for OS 3.0 I do not get any symbolic information, however if I use 3.1 they all appear.